# doxygen docbook Output Files

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to create an API users manual for a C project.
I have set Doxygen file to generate XML,HTML, and DocBook outputs.
I plan on using the DocBook files to be the base for a users manual.
The HTML files looks ok, XML has all of the information BUT DocBook xml files has about half of the information for any given function compared with XML or HTML.

What setting am I missing for DocBook to include more detail?

Here is the header I am using:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * @brief
 *      Validate command line string for correct command parameters
 *
 * @param  SeqCmd_T* seqCmd    - Sequence command object to evaluate
 *
 * @return
 *      bool        - true = validated, false = non validated
 *
 * Details
 *      SeqCmd_T->paramStr.tokens[0] = SignalName, "Slot1"
 *      SeqCmd_T->paramStr.tokens[1] = Dwell, "1"
 *
 */
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What kind of information are you missing?, it might be that not all items are integrated yet / can be integrated.

Comment: I am using the cygwin environment, doxygen version 1.8.14. In the function header I am using a @details tab for low level information. This info shows up in the HTML but not in DocBook file.

Comment: I checked the given example and the details are not going into the docbook documentation (tough they land in HTML, LaTeX / PDF, XML documentation). I think that not all items of docbook are integrated in the output (needs further study and I don't know the docbook format). Feel free to submit a, small complete, issue to the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new). See to it that the output in the HTML version goes without warnings (param command)

Comment: I moved header information to question, as it is not an answer but giving information regarding the question and should be here (answer can be deleted).

Comment: I've just pushed a proposed patch with a new implementation of the docbook generator, pull request #6487 (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6487)

Comment: Code of pull request #6487 has been integrated in master on github.